# Handeling my Many-to-Many relation api requests in asp.net core3.1 webapi

Tags: c#, relational-database, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-3.1, webapi

I posted my issues as a diagram so you can understand what is it.
I have two issues as you can see:

1. How can I save my entries for related join table during CRUD operation on Course table? what endpoints do you suggest?
2. How can I get my list of Courses for a specific Category and in reverse? Get courses for a category and Get categories for a course

I already have my endpoints for Course and Category tables but these two issues that I want to solve. how might I expose this relationship in a RESTful API?

I got a list for categories for every course in my response when I send a GET request to /api/courses or /api/courses/{courseid}.

[image: My Issue Diagram]

Comment: For your first issue,you need to pass courseId and List<CategoryId> to save data to the related join table.If you only pass a courseId,it is hard to find related categories,So it is hard to solve it by Course CRUD.For your second issue,you need to pass a categoryId,and search the related coursIds in related join table,and then find the  courses by the related courseIds.So for the second issue,you also need to get the data from related join table,not only to get data from crud of course or category.

Comment: Yes, you are right. It is better to search for the categories. Thank you

Comment: @MohebYarahmadi What program did you use to draw the picture to the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should follow this template:

GET /api/categories/{id}/courses => Get All courses of a category

POST /api/categories/{id}/courses => Add a course to a category

DELETE /api/categories/{id}/courses/{id} => Remove the course from the category

... And so on.